# Nicescroll not displaying when div

Tags: jquery, nicescroll

It perfectly works on HTML ...

```
$("html").niceScroll({zindex: 10002, autohidemode:true, cursorcolor:"#FF9933", horizrailenabled:false});
```

... but if I try to show it on a div like this (where aviso_float_content is the hidden div that must be displayed with the nicescroll scrollbar within it) ...

```
$("#aviso_float_content").niceScroll({zindex: 11002, autohidemode:false, cursorcolor:"#FF9933", horizrailenabled:false});
```

... there is no way. Div's content is scrollable, but no scrollbar is shown. Without this code the windows standard scrollbar shows and works fine, but I wanted the nice scroll one instead. I've already tried, unsuccessfuly, appending the following script ...

```
$("#aviso_float_content").mouseover(function() {
    $("#aviso_float_content").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it, aviso_float_content is hidden?

Comment: Yes. At the first time aviso_float_content is hidden. There is `display: none;` in the CSS, but by the time a _'Legal Notice'_ button is clicked this jquery ... `$("#aviso_float_content").css("display", "block");` ... turns aviso_float_content to visible.